# ClosedXML: Dependent dropdown remove empty options

Tags: c#, .net, excel, closedxml

I have this table in excel :

| A | B | C | D |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 5 |  |
| 2 | 6 |  |  |
| 3 | 7 | 8 | 9 |

Where 4 and 5 are the children of 1, 6 - of 2, and 7, 8 and 9 - of 3.
I want a dependent dropdown list where in cell E1 i have a dropdown with the options 1,2 and 3, and in cell F1 I will have the options 4 and 5 if 1 is chosen in E1 and so on.

my code looks like this:

```csharp
ws.Cell("A1").InsertData(new []{ 1,2,3});
ws.Cell("B1").InsertData(new []{ 4,5}, true); // this transposes the data, making it a row instead of a column
ws.Cell("B2").InsertData(new []{ 6}, true);
ws.Cell("B3").InsertData(new []{ 7,8,9}, true);
ws.Range("A1:A3").AddToNamed("Parents");
ws.Range("B1:D3").AddToNamed("Children");
var parentCell = ws.Cell("E1");
parentCell.CreateDataValidation().List(ws.Range("A1:A3"), true);
var childCell = ws.Cell("F1");
childCell.CreateDataValidation().List("=INDEX(Children,MATCH(E1,Parents,0),0)", true);
```

This works fine but the problem is that when I select 1 or 2 in E1, there are empty options in the F1 dropdown menu. How do I remove these?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I named each of the child lists as a separate range in excel and in the F1 cell i used `INDIRECT` to reference the value in E1. i added _ to the names of the ranges because a range name cannot start with a number, and added an _ when comparing E1's value to the range names. Code now looks like this

```
ws.Cell("A1").InsertData(new []{ 1,2,3});
ws.Cell("B1").InsertData(new []{ 4,5}, true); // this transposes the data, making it a row instead of a column
ws.Cell("B2").InsertData(new []{ 6}, true);
ws.Cell("B3").InsertData(new []{ 7,8,9}, true);
ws.Range("B1:C1").AddToNamed("_1");
ws.Range("B2:B2").AddToNamed("_2");
ws.Range("B3:D3").AddToNamed("_3");
var parentCell = ws.Cell("E1");
parentCell.CreateDataValidation().List(ws.Range("A1:A3"), true);
var childCell = ws.Cell("F1");
childCell.CreateDataValidation().List("=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(\"_\", $E$1))", true);
```